# Convert java project to apache-tomcat hosted project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created an application that is running locally without server. It recieves data through a socket, processes it and then sends the result back.
I want to host it on a local apache-tomcat server using Eclipse, and I already created the server.
How can I run the program on the server ? Do I have to convert the project to a web project ?
Couldn't find any tutorial except for webpage-creating projects...

Thanks

Comment: Create a dynamic project and link the java files to the actual project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using sockets, there is a good chance Tomcat won't be serving your needs. As for web application projects, you need to use, e.g. Servlets to serve requests on server wrappers like Tomcat.

Comment: So I should change my project to use a servlet instead of a socket ?

Comment: Exactly. If you are planning to deploy it as a web application, servlets is the way to go. Sockets are handled inside the Tomcat wrapper itself.